# Error Fetching http headers in wsdltophp.com

Tags: php, soap, wsdl2php

I am using wsdltophp.com to generate php files that access a web service.

Everything works fine except when I am using one service that will probably take a while to run. After 60 seconds it gives up and I get this error:

> Error Fetching http headers

After looking at other answers on stackoverflow.com I assume this is just a timeout error and I can find some suggestions on how to fix it, but I am not sure how to work those suggestions into the files from wsdltophp.com. Can anybody help me with that?

The suggestions included disabling "keep_alive" and editing "default_socket_timeout". But where do I edit these settings in the wsdltophp.com files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5000);
```

did the trick for me.